# How can I make pulseaudio have a programs output as a separate stream?

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

So, what I want to do (or at least I think I do) is make the output of running "play "|rec -d pitch -310"" to be a separate pulseaudio thing(?), so that another program can use it as input. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: FYI, the program acts as a voice changer.

Answer (score 0):

Fire up the 'voice changer' and open Pulse Audio Volume Control.  On the 'Recording' tab you should see the app you are using listed, in this case for the 'rec -d pitch -310' command it shows "ALSA plug-in [sox]" for me. There is a button to select the capture device, typically 'Built-in Audio Analog Stereo' which is the built in mic.  On the playback tab you can do the same and select where the output goes like 'Built-in Audio Analog Stereo' (speakers).  This only shows apps that are currently attached to the audio, so make sure your app is running.

Now start up the second program that is going to use it as input. Locate this application in the 'Recording' tab in Pulse Audio.  For this, select "Monitor of {device that is selected as playback for other program}".

[image]

That should do it. However there is one drawback and that is if the second program is also using the same playback device, there is the potential for feedback.  I've used this setup with FireRTC and it seems to cancel out some of the feedback, sometimes it cancels out too much.  Other apps don't and it just echos incoming audio back.  If the second app isn't generating audio, it will work fine.  If the two apps are set to different playback devices (like a USB headset and built in audio), you might be able to eliminate this issue.  You can also fire up a dummy sound device to pipe audio through using:

```
sudo modprobe snd-dummy
```